# How Can i disable AD enforce the computer name uniqueness

Tags: active-directory

I have a parc of computer who running with the same programs ; I have the image of my computer who i deploy on the others programs without changing any configuration only IP change

How can i do for AD accept to rigester the computer with the same name

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that you can. Each computer that joins the domain has an account created for it using the computer name, that account needs to be unique for each computer, and AD needs to be able to communicate with each individual computer.